# JQGRID inline dropdown binding via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

[image]

`jQuery(document).ready(function () {`

```
var grid = $("#list");

    var AllCategory={"1":"Computing","2":"Cooking","10":"Fiction","3":"Finance","6":"Language","4":"Medical","11":"News","8":"Philosophy","9":"Religion","7":"Sport","5":"Travel"};


    grid.jqGrid({
        url: '/SupplierOrder/Select_SupplierOrderDetailByX/',
        editurl: "clientArray",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Category', 'Qty'],
        colModel: [
                      {
                          name: 'Category', index: 'CategoryID', align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select',
                          editoptions: { value: AllCategory }, editrules: { required: true }
                      },
                      { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 40, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: "35", maxlength: "50"} }
                 ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: '',
        sortorder: '',
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        autoheight: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/black-tie/images',
        caption: 'Supplier Order Detail'
    })
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, refresh: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, {});
    grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
        addtext: "Add",
        edittext: "Edit",
        savetext: "Save",
        canceltext: "Cancel"
    });

});
```

It is my JQGrid.

Then, I remove below code ...

```
var AllCategory={"1":"Computing","2":"Cooking","10":"Fiction","3":"Finance","6":"Language","4":"Medical","11":"News","8":"Philosophy","9":"Religion","7":"Sport","5":"Travel"};
```

Replace with below code so that i can get dynamic data ...

```
var AllCategory = (function () {
var list = null;

$.ajax({
async: false,
global: false,
type: "POST",
url: 'Category_Lookup',
dataType: 'json',
data: {},
success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    list = response;
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("jqXHR.responseText --> " + jqXHR.responseText + "\njqXHR --> " + jqXHR + "\ntextStatus --> " + textStatus + " \nerrorThrown --> " + errorThrown);
}
});
alert(list);

return list;
})();
```

Firstly, I get below message box ...

[image]

Then I get Error

[image]

Could anyone please tell me how to make it correct ?
Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong. It should be:

```
<select><option value=“1”>One</option> <option value=“2”>Two</option></select>
```

Check http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config (dataUrl).

Here is a working example. The info is taken from the database and then formatted in the corresponding Controller action.

```
<th role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr">
 <div style="width:100%;position:relative;height:100%;padding-right:0.3em;">
  <select name="TypeCode" id="gs_TypeCode" style="width: 100%; ">
   <option></option>
   <option value="1">cosas!</option>
   <option value="2">mascosas</option>
   <option value="3">yast</option>
   <option value="4">tiparraco</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</th>
```

Sorry for the crappy format but I cannot post images...
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your help @smp, `<select><option value=“1”> ...` is not my code. It is auto-generated by JQGRID according to my JSON string `{"1":"Computing","2" ...`

Comment: Then, Let me request you, please read my question again. You will see that there is 2 ways which i tried to bind dropdownlist.

Comment: Frist way is using static JSON string, then everything is correct, but when i use dynamic JSON string via ajax, then Error occur.

Comment: Thank you for your help again @smp. Finally I know which part of my code give me that error. Problem line is here `success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    list = response;
},`

Comment: I do need to convert JSON format `list = $.parseJSON(response);`, SO i change it ,and it is ok now. Anyway, I do appreciate your help. Thank you @smp